# Best Practices for Deploying Timer jobs in Server Farm Environments with multiple WFE

Tags: timer-jobs, 2007

I've a timer job which I want to run only once per day, for the entire farm. How do I

1. Deploy it in a multiple WFE environment? Do I run the `stsadm -o deploysolution` command in every WFE, or just the one where I want to run it?
2. Where should I activate the feature? Should it be activated only from a particular WFE?
3. What should be the value of the SPJobLockType?

Answer (score 5):

Hi
you should build ONE solution (WSP package) which you deploy ONCE. The package contents/timer jobs will be replicated to all your SharePoint services. You should activate it at Farm level - since its a Farm level job. And if you want it to run only on one WFE in your farm set SPJobLockType to **Job**.